# Intuition behind derivatives of linear forms

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

In my machine learning course, we're kicking off by revising some concepts from linear algebra and calculus. The instructor has introduced the notion of linear forms, i.e. a function $$f:\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, f(\underline{s})=A \underline{s} $$
where $\underline{s}$ is a $p \text{ x } 1$ vector and $A$ is a $n \text{ x } p$ matrix of real numbers.

The instructor has said that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=A $$
I am having trouble wrapping my head around this concept, but am willing to take it on faith. I give an example to better illustrate my lack of understanding.
Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\underline{s}=\begin{pmatrix}
s_1\\
s_2
\end{pmatrix} $$
Then here $$f(\underline{s})=\begin{pmatrix}
s_1+2s_2\\
2s_1+s_2
\end{pmatrix} $$
From here, how do we obtain that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix} $$
I.e. what steps do we follow to go from our $2$ x $1$ vector to our $2$ x $2$ matrix?

Comment: The intuition for derivatives/differentials of some function $f$ in general is that they are the "best" linear approximation of $f$. When $f$ itself is linear, then it is its own best linear approximation. In the case of maps between vector spaces, the differential is represented by the Jacobian (at points where the function is differentiable).

Comment: I've also had difficulty wrapping my head around this. I prefer calculating directional derivatives. Consider any smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Given any vector $v$, the directional derivative of $f$ at $s$ in the direction $v$ is $$D_vf(s) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} f(s(t)), $$ which is a vector. This is a linear function of $v$ and therefore there is a matrix $M$ (depending on $f$ and $s$) such that $$D_vf(s) = Mv.$$ The matrix $M$ is what your professor is calling $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$$

Comment: Don't take it on faith. Just compute the derivatives and see for yourself that what you get is that.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is a linear approximation of a function. Using the notation of your question (which I consider not too appropriate, but it will do), this means that in a given point $s_0$ there is a linear map (denoted by $\frac{\partial f(s_0)}{\partial s}$) such that
$$f( s_0 + h)= f(s_0) + \frac{\partial f(s_0)}{\partial s}h + g(|h|)$$
where $g$ is a function which is decreasing fast to $0$ in the sense that even $g(|h|)/|h|$ converges to $0$ if $h$ does. This $g$ ensures that there is at most one map $\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ with that property and that that choice is, in a very precise sense, the optimal linear approximation of $f$.

The term $\frac{\partial f(s_0)}{\partial s}h $ is meant to mean applying the linear map $\frac{\partial f(s_0)}{\partial s} $ (which you can think of as a matrix) to the vector $h$.

Now if you take $f(s) = As$ for some matrix $A$ (i.e. $s\mapsto As$ is linear), this reduces to
$$ A(s_0 + h) = As_0 + Ah = As_0 + \frac{\partial f(s_0)}{\partial s}h + g(|h|)$$

This is, obviously, fulfilled, with $g\equiv 0$, if you choose $\frac{\partial f(s_0)}{\partial s}=A$, and this just means that the best linear approximation of a linear map is that same linear map.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a linear function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$, we can represent the function by a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$ and write $$f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}ax_1+bx_2\\cx_1+dx_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}$$ which gives us two coordinate functions $$y_1=ax_1+bx_2\\y_2=cx_1+dx_2$$

To differentiate a function like $f$ we form the matrix consisting of the gradient of each coordinate function in its corresponding row. This gives $$Df=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2}\\\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$